# Is the Wonderlic test cross validated by any other test or data?

Tags: intelligence, employment

In a quite famous [lecture](https://youtu.be/fjs2gPa5sD0?t=109) Jordan Peterson lists what IQ you need to work in certain professions, based on the Wonderlic test.

Are there other sources to these claims than Wonderlic that gives similar (or different) results? I googled but could only find unsourced Quora answers and similar.

Comment: What even are those bullet points?  One of them says "Manager, Trainee" what is he even implying with that?

Comment: He's implying that to get a job as a trainee manager, you generally have to have the IQ he talks about.

Comment: Who is James Peterson and what is the Wonderlic test? Now I have to Google twice... Please add links.

Comment: Isn't this question essentially *Does the Wonderlic test work?*

Comment: @JanDoggen With a small side order of 'does it correspond to IQ?'

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Peterson's point doesn't rely on exact results. If Wonderlic was off by 10% or 20% it would make no difference. I'm struggling to see the importance of this question.

Comment: The title and the contents of this question seem to be totally unrelated. The Wonderlic Wonscore is not the same as IQ. Find a claim about Wonscore, and we can evaluated if it is true. If you want to go by Peterson's claim, please transcribe something specific he claims.

Answer (score 4):

[Does IQ Really Predict Job Performance?](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4557354/) -- published in Applied Developmental Science 2015 Jul 3; 19(3): 153–169 -- concludes (among other points) that:

> - Supporters of IQ testing have been quick to point to correlations
>     between IQ and job performance as evidence of test validity. A closer
>     look at the data and results, however, suggests a rather murkier
>     picture.
> - Hundreds of studies prior to the 1970s reported low and/or
>     inconsistent correlations between IQ and job performance.
> - The claim that the IQ-job performance correlation increases with job
>     complexity is not born out in more recent studies.

This supports the claim that the topic has been widely-studied, if that's what this question is trying to get at.